# jsf forEach over collection

Tags: jsf, jstl

Hi I'm trying to iterate through java Collection to write down its content. Unfortunately following code doesn't work:

```
 <c:forEach items="#{company.companyWarehouseCollection}" var="warehouse" varStatus="status" rendered="#{company.companyWarehouseCollection.size()}">
     test data
 </c:forEach>
```

This is strange because printing value of **#{company.companyWarehouseCollection.size()}** gives me positive data different than 0.

Comment: Why did you use rendered ? Delete it and try again.

Comment: I've used it to make sute that collection of entity was successfully initiated. Removing this does nothing.

Comment: Did you clean your project ?

Comment: Woah.. Strange. Did you check your code in debug mode and are you sure about the collection is not empty ?

Comment: What happens, if you try the same with `ui:repeat`?

Comment: `rendered=""` is waiting for a `Boolean`, not an `Integer`.

Comment: `<c:forEach>` doesn't have a `rendered` attribute to begin with. Please post valid code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ui:repeat var="cli" value="#{beanCDI.clientes}">
      <h:outputText value="#{cli}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Please explain the cause and the solution in clear and easy to understand terms instead of only saying "try this" along with solely a code snippet.